# Excel Interop Apply Chart Template

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

**Problem Overview:**

I am automating the report generation (excel) for a customer using C# with "native" excel support (microsoft.office.interop.excel) and the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library.

My customer is not very flexible about charts design so my charts must have the exact same style as theirs.

No problem, i exported their chart templates using Excel 2010

**What does not work:**

I can't apply any chart template via code

**What i have tried:**

1 - EPPlus : Have no support for loading templates to charts

2 - InteropExcel : Fails on applying the template raising an exception, here is my code:

```
        Application excelApp = null;
        Workbook    workbook = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;

        try
        {
            excelApp  = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            workbook  = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(config.DiretorioRelatorio);
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets[Consts.RECOVERED_SHEET];

            string template = config["templatePath"]; // .crtx file

            ChartObjects charts = worksheet.ChartObjects ();
            ChartObject chart   = ((ChartObject)charts.Item (0));
            chart.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate(template);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            workbook.Save ();
            workbook.Close ();
            excelApp.Quit ();

            ReleaseObject (worksheet);
            ReleaseObject (workbook);
            ReleaseObject (excelApp);
        }
```

This code either throws:

1 -  `excel interop HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` (on casting ChartObjects[0] to ChartObject)

2 - `The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))`

**TL:DR:**

How can i apply a chart template from a file, to an existing chart on my spreadsheet using C# ?

**EDIT:**

Pastebin code : [ExcelInteropProblem](http://pastebin.com/a91x0Lpz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes in VBA aren't zero based, so when going from .Net to Excel Interop, you start at 1 even though indexes in C# are, so change this:

```
ChartObject chart   = ((ChartObject)charts.Item (0));
```

To this:

```
ChartObject chart   = ((ChartObject)charts.Item (1));
```

Comment: i have tried to change for one instead, and the conversion problem is solved, but i still have problems when invoking the excel app like 90% of the times.

I kill all excel.exe processed before calling the interop com for the excel app but it still throws me an exception as stated above : RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER

Comment: That's strange, I've done a lot of interop stuff and never seen that error, are you threading at all?

Comment: The call to this method is done into an STA Thread, called from the main thread.

After starting the STA Thread, the main thread wait until it ends (based on the return of the method i decide whether i should retry or not). The same problem occurs when the method is called within the main thread by the way

Comment: Have you left out code in your code sample? Do you declare the Application object in one place, and use it in another (maybe pass it into this method) or do you declare it just before you use it?

Comment: Edited Question with pastebin code that might help you understand what i am doing and how i am doing it