# Trying to create an excel chart in a XLS file with data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop, excel-interop

My problem currently is that the data shows up like it's suppose to in the excel file but the chart doesn't appear correctly. I am trying Method 1: http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel.
I have already looked at this: [Excel Interop Apply Chart Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883776/excel-interop-apply-chart-template?rq=1)

Charts: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl6E8.jpg)
The top image is what I get the bottom image is what I want.

```
    string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
        //C:\appdata...\LicenseCheck
    string folderPath = string.Format(@"{0}\LicenseCheck", tempPath);
      //The csv file with the XMAX license usage stats
    string secondPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_Report_Stats_{2}_{3}.csv", 
        folderPath, productName, lastCheckedDate.Month, lastCheckedDate.Year);

    var application = new Application();
        var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(secondPath);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as Worksheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        // Add chart.
        var charts = worksheet.ChartObjects() as ChartObjects;
        var chartObject = charts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300) as ChartObject;
        var chart = chartObject.Chart;

        // Set chart range.
        var range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", "C25");
        chart.SetSourceData(range);

        // Set chart properties.
        chart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
        chart.ChartWizard
        (
            Source: range
           // Title: "graphTitle",
           // CategoryTitle: "xAxis",
           // ValueTitle: "yAxis"
        );

        chartObject.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate(@"C:\\LicenseUsageStatsTemplate.crtx");

        // Save.
        workbook.SaveAs("Stats.xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
        workbook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        application.Quit();

        releaseObject(worksheet);
        releaseObject(workbook);
        releaseObject(application);
```

Comment: A chart cannot be created in a CSV file. I think you need to use SaveAs to save the file as an Excel workbook (xlsx).

Comment: So I changed the filename in `string secondPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_Report_Stats_{2}_{3}.csv", 
        folderPath, productName, lastCheckedDate.Month, lastCheckedDate.Year);` to `.xlsx` and interop couldn't open xlsx files. Then, I changed it to `.xls`. But, the graph still doesn't show up.

Comment: Changing the extension doesn't force Excel to save to a different file format. Read up on the `SaveAs` method in the language reference. You'll find there's a parameter for setting the file format - use that.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks!, I have updated the question because the chart doesn't appear correctly. I want to edit the chart programatically. We can use a template like I did above (which doesn't work currently). But, I don't think its preferable.

Comment: Found this: [Changing Axis Labels on Excel Chart created in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779376/changing-axis-labels-on-excel-chart-created-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that MS office had to be installed on the server to use Interop. So, ended up using EPPlus. It's an awesome library that uses OfficeOpenXML.